# Directx Toolkit with a Xaml app

Tags: c++, xaml, directx, windows-phone-8

I am trying to make a Direct3D with XAML app, and I am wanting to use the DirectX Toolkit (for Windows Phone 8). I am just modifying the VS2012 **Windows Phone Direct3D with XAML App** template.

I have been using two examples off of the DirectX Toolkit's Codeplex Samples page. Primarily [this one.](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/DirectX_on_Windows_Phone%3a_2D_Game_Example_using_DirectX_Toolkit)

The error comes about when I try to load a ID3D11ShaderResourceView*. If I have the following code

```
DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        CreateDDSTextureFromFile(m_d3dDevice.Get(),
                    L"CatTexture.dds",
                    nullptr,
                    &m_catTexture,
                    MAXSIZE_T)
        );
```

in the CreateDeviceResources() method (CubeRenderer.cs), I get an InvalidAccessException on the line:

```
DrawingSurfaceBackground.SetBackgroundContentProvider(
         m_d3dBackground.CreateContentProvider()
);
```

in MainPage.xaml.cs

Is it possible to make the DirectX Toolkit work with xaml?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing does not appear to be related with **CreateDDSTextureFromFile**, make sure that you have the file CatTexture.dds added to the project as content and that its on the root path or else add the path to the filename "/path/CatTexture.dds".